# dom parser getElement

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I want to only get restaurants in beirut with dom parser please help

this is a part from my xml file :

city -> beirut->restaurants->restaurant->name->

```
    tyr->restaurants->restaurant->name-> 

    jbeil->restaurants->restaurant->name->
```

```
<restaurants>

  <restaurant>

     <name>
     ...

 </restaurant>

</restaurants>
```

```
<restaurants>

  <restaurant>

     <name>

     ...

 </restaurant>

</restaurants>
```

```
<restaurants>

  <restaurant>

     <name>

     ...

 </restaurant>

</restaurants>
```

because this code give me all restaurants in all city's :

try {

```
 File inputFile = new File("src/josephXml.xml");

     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 

        = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();






     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Restaurant");

     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);


       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

           Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 



            jTextArea1.append( "\n"+"Name      :   "+ eElement
              .getElementsByTagName("name")
              .item(0)
              .getTextContent()+"\n "
```

, i only want restaurants in beirut please help

Answer (score 0):

You use Restaurant, but your file uses restaurant. It's not OK, because case sensitive.

use XPath: you can select many things, it is very readable.

Replace this in your code:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression="/city/beirut/restaurants/restaurant";

NodeList nList = (NodeList)  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```